# Accessing variables and arguments in IDL + Java

Tags: java, variables, arguments, corba, idl

I am investigating distributed systems right now, so... I have to learn that IDL thingy. :D
I have this requirement:

*Define in IDL
- an account as an struct
- accounts as a sequence of account’s
- an interface Customer with some account operations:
**payIn (amount, accountId), - returns true if success, else false
getAccounts (name), - returns a sequence of accounts (belonging to the person)**
- an interface Administrator with account operations:
**create a new account
delete an account***

and this is my .idl file:

```
module AccountNaming
{
    struct Account
    {
        long id;
        double balance;
        string name;    
    };

    typedef sequence<Account> accounts;

    interface Customer
    {
        boolean payIn(in double amount, in long accountId);
        accounts getAccounts(in string name);
        string helloCust();
    };
    interface Administrator
    {
        void createAcc();
        void deleteAcc();
        string helloAdmin();
    };
};
```

I have generated all the POA, Helper, Holder classes for IDL.

In my Java code I have a class that uses the IDL code:

```
import AccountNaming.*;
public class CustomerImpl extends CustomerPOA
{
   public String helloCust()
   {
      return "Hello, dear Customer! :) ";
   }

   @Override
   public boolean payIn(double amount, int accountId)
   {
      // how to get to the Customer's local variables ?
      super.Customer.setAmount... // or something like that, because this doesn't work... etc.
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Account[] getAccounts(String name)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
   }
}
```

I know that the .idl file is correct. the "helloCust/admin" methods work. My question is how to access the variables of the Customer/Administrator so I can set them as arguments in the *payIn , getAccounts* methods...

Comment: `Customer` is an Interface without any variable, right?

Comment: I think your "workflow" is still unclear. Who creates customers? What is the key that identifies a Customer... How an Administrator shall manage the Customers?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a facade or factory to allow you to get access to your `Customer/Administrator` interfaces, so in your IDL you would also have:

```
interface UserFactory 
{
   Customer getCustomer(String customerName);
   Administrator getAdministrator(String credentials); 
}
```

The implementation of this interface would have you look up the any details from database, etc.

Using this, you probably won't need the `name` field in `getAccounts()` (unless this is used for filtering) and you can do:

```
Account[] accounts = getAccounts("not-needed-anymore");
for (Account account : accounts) {
   if (account.id == accountId) {
      account.balance += amount;
      break;
   }
}
```

This will update your `Account` array information but you will still need to persist the data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the quick answer, Reimeus, but I thought of a simpler solution:

```
public boolean payIn(double amount, int accountNumber)
    {
        boolean success = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < accountList.length; i++)
        {
            if(accountList[i].accountNumber == accountNumber)
            {
                accountList[i].balance += amount;
                success = true;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public account[] getAccounts(String name)
    {
        account[] accounts;
        int numberOfAccounts = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < accountList.length; i++)
        {
           if(accountList[i] != null)
            if(accountList[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            {
                numberOfAccounts++;
            }
        }
        if(numberOfAccounts != 0)
        {
            accounts = new account[numberOfAccounts];
            for(int i = 0; i < accountList.length; i++)
            {
                if(accountList[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                {
                    accounts[count] = accountList[i];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return accounts;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```